# How to set iPhone tab bar icon in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am using the same ViewController for several different views.

When instantiating the ViewController for a specific view, is there an easy way to specify the tab bar icon via code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
yourViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Name", @"Name")
image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_ yourViewController.png"]
tag:3];
```

The viewControllers are added to the tab bar, so the image and names should be set before the tab bar becomes visible (appDelegate if they are there on app start for instance). After that, you could use the above code to change the icon and text from the loadView or viewDidAppear within that viewController.

Comment: this doesn't work in iOS 4.x and you forgot to release the memory

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your `UITabBar` has a property called `items`, which is an array of `UITabBarItem`s for each tab bar item. You can create a `UITabBarItem` using the `–initWithTitle:image:tag:` constructor to use your own image, or the `–initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:` constructor to use a system image.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in the AppDelegate, by declaring a UITabBarController iVar and pointing it to the applications tabBarController. You can access the individual titles using the `items` array. and the `setTitle`.

```
@synthesize tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSArray* items = [self.tabBarController.tabBar items];
    [[items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Home"];
    [[items objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Cool"];
    [[items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"Stuff"];
    [[items objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:@"Settings"];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is : Add this below line in viewDidLoad

```
    [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<Image Name>"]];
```

to viewcontrollers which are set inside UITabBarController