# Load tableview on first start up only and populate tab bar accordingly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

Ok I'm making an iPhone app that (only on the first time the user opens the app) loads a tableview with a list of, for example, sports teams. The user checks the sports teams he wants and taps the done button. Then the tab bar loads with the teams the user selected in the tab bar. Any way how to do this as far as a tutorial/ code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link may help you: [How to set iPhone tab bar icon in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449409/how-to-set-iphone-tab-bar-icon-in-code). For more help on how to use TabBarControllers, there are tons of sample code AND sample projects found here: [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Hope that helps!